# Get last record by day from each group

Tags: mysql

[image: The table]

I made a query to select all the sum of all metrics and everything is fine but I can't figure it out how to select the CommunitySize data from the last day of a month / AccountId.

Now the query return the CommunitySize data from the first day of each month / AccountId.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
a.Id AS AccountId,
a.Name AS AccountName,
a.Label AS AccountLabel,
a.Status AS AccountStatus,
a.Link AS AccountLink,
sp.Name AS SocialPlatformName,
sd.Date AS SocialDataDate,
SUM(sd.Comment) AS Comments,
SUM(sd.PostLike) AS PostLikes,
SUM(sd.TotalReach) AS TotalReach,
SUM(sd.Share) AS Shares,
SUM(sd.Click) AS Clicks,
sd.CommunitySize,
c.Id AS CountryId,
c.CountryName AS CountryName
FROM social_data sd, account a, country c, social_platform sp
WHERE sd.AccountId = a.Id AND a.CountryId = c.Id AND sd.AccountId IS NOT NULL AND a.TypeId = sp.Id AND a.Status = 1
GROUP BY MONTH(sd.Date), sd.AccountId
```

Comment: providing an sqlfiddle can be very nice

Comment: @Vanojx1 sorry, I had some things to do at work. I'll try to provide an sqlfiddle later, when I get home

Comment: @Vanojx1 the character limit from sqlfiddle is 8000. I can't provide an appropriate sqlfiddle for my problem ...